# How many characters can be uploaded through a textarea in a form?

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, http, textarea

Is there a limit such as 65,535 or 32,767 on how many characters can be sent to a server via a textarea in an HTML form?  Update: via **POST** only

I want to develop a way for my users to upload large amounts of text (say 1 million characters) by allowing them to cut and paste on their computers, instead of uploading files.

I don't care about non-modern browsers. Chrome, Firefox, IE10 are fine (preferably IE9 too).

**Update:** I don't mean the title question literally. I just need to know if the limit is less than say 100 million or 1 million. There will likely be browser-specific limits on pasting a few GB of text into a textarea. It will likely be interesting to know, but may be not worth the effort.

Comment: Via POST, GET or both?

Comment: @j08691 thanks. POST only. (updating question)

Comment: Check this link: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/set-maxlength-of-textarea-input-using-jquery-javascript/

Comment: @Jatin I am afraid you did not understand the question (or perhaps the blog post you linked to).

Comment: Is this information being stored in a database? If so you could run into limits there, don't remember specifics off the top of my head.

Comment: @Jobokai I can handle limits everywhere. I just need to know whether there is a limit at the `textarea` level, and if so, what is it so that I can plan for it. Database, Queue, File System, are all OK. I know how to handle them. The scope of this question is solely on how much can be pasted into `<textarea>` on a modern browser and how much of it can be POSTed by the browser to a willing and capable server.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find much info on a browser-imposed limit on textarea content, which leads me to believe that there is none. Therefore it now depends entirely on the method you use to send the data. A simple Google search revealed all you need to know.

### GET

According to the RFC:

> The HTTP protocol does not place any a priori limit on the length of a
>   URI. Servers MUST be able to handle the URI of any resource they
>   serve, and SHOULD be able to handle URIs of unbounded length if they
>   provide GET-based forms that could generate such URIs. A server SHOULD
>   return 414 (Request-URI Too Long) status if a URI is longer than the
>   server can handle (see section 10.4.15).
>
> Note: Servers should be cautious about depending on URI lengths above
>   255 bytes, because some older client or proxy implementations may not
>   properly support these lengths.

Not a hard-and-fast limit, but a good recommendation.

### POST

If you have access the php.ini file, you can actually adjust this.

```
#set max post size
php_value post_max_size 20M
```

I have never adjusted this setting (since I don't need to), but there are many people who have with success.

Comment: +1 thanks for the confirmation; I could not find any limit either. the php.ini is not relevant because I am not trying to limit it (and also I am not using PHP).  I just want to be sure that users will be able to copy/paste and upload large amounts of text (instead of having to manage files) before I implement this solution.